# getting exit value of actual command in process builder

Tags: java, jar, cmd, processbuilder

i am using ProcessBuilder for executing windows command through java code , here is my code

```
String[] command = {"cmd.exe","/c","jar.exe"};
ProcessBuilder processBuilder  = new ProcessBuilder(command);
Process pro = processBuilder.start();
pro.waitFor();
int j = pro.exitValue();
```

in this case i am getting exitValue of "cmd.exe" , how can i get exitValue of "jar.exe" command

Regards

Comment: Have you tried executing just `jar.exe`?

Comment: yes if your java is there in system path it works otherwise it wont